# Blackscreen when navigate to new page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

At the moment I create an App where I display my sensor data in a List but my problem is that if I want to navigate to the List page I always get a Blackscreen.
I tried to navigate like this:

```
Container(
                  height: 150.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>  DataPage(key: null,)));

                      },
```

and I get the error

```
The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Key'.
```

and that's part of my code for the List Page

```
class DataPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataPage({
    required Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hive Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: _buildListView()),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

with my current knowledge I don´t know how to solve my problem. Sorry for any grammar mistakes and I would be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you're passing 'null' in Key while navigation to DataPage screen. Key is optional parameter, hence you can make it nullable this way.

Edits to your first snippet:

```
Container(
                  height: 150.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 25, 75, 100),
                  child: Material(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    elevation: 7.0,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>  DataPage()));

                      },
```

Edits to your second snippet:

```
class DataPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DataPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hive Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: _buildListView()),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your constructor in data page like this :

```
   const DataPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).